# Требуется код, позволяющий отображать вводимую пользователем информацию на LCD 1602. MicroPython

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Пишу программу, вроде калькулятора на MicroPython для устройства Raspberry Pi Pico. Для вывода информации взял дисплей 16 столбцов на 2 строки (LCD 1602). Я не знаю как написать код, позволяющий видеть вводимую пользователем информацию на этом дисплее во время ввода (Как на обычном калькуляторе). Пока что я на этапе того, когда информация вводится в консоли, после нажимается Enter, а уже потом она отображается на дисплее. Но мне надо сразу видеть информацию в дисплее, что бы например исправить её, или видеть, что вводишь. Для работы с дисплеем брал библиотеки по следующей ссылке: https://github.com/dhylands/python_lcd .

Comment: С выводом, допустим, понятно, а как у вас пользователь информацию вводит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @insolor . Пока что информация вводится с клавиатуры ПК в среде разработки Thonny (я подключаю Raspberry Pi Pico USB шнуром к ПК для питания и работы с микроконтроллером). В дальнейшем - припаяю тактовые кнопки для обозначения чисел.

Comment: Ну, как я понимаю, Thonny общается с платой по serial, micropython работает в интерактивном режиме. Работа через тактовые кнопки будет довольно значительно отличаться от этого. Нужно для начала попробовать реализовать на одной кнопке, чтобы при ее нажатии добавлялась какая-то цифра на LCD. Просто цикл `while True` по сути, внутри проверяется состояние кнопки (состояние пина, к которому кнопка припаяна), при нажатом состоянии вызвать функцию вывода на LCD.